# SIMD mode for RGSW encryption?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, lwe, ring-lwe

I know schemes like [BFV](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/144.pdf), [BGV](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/277.pdf), and [CKKS](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/421.pdf) supports SIMD operations where the plaintext is vector of values instead of polynomial. I am wondering if [RGSW/TFHE](https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/15659/introfhetfhe.pdf) kind of schemes can also support SIMD operations?

As explained in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/736.pdf) RGSW can be defined as list of BFV cipher texts so I am thinking if it can also take advantage of BFV SIMD?